# Best Linux distro for cross-compiling to SUA

Tags: windows, linux, cross-compiling, sua, interix

I'm very interested in using Linux / GCC for cross-compiling to Microsoft SUA (Subsystem for Unix Applications) format (I have SUA 6.1 as part of Windows 7, 64-bits). Using SUA to natively compile programs and their dependencies is a hassle given the general lacklustre support by MS, no real package manager, etc. What is the best way to do this using Linux? I am open to other approaches, but personally envision Linux as part of the solution. If there are better cross-compilers for the job I'd like to know- seems that I'd have to opt for an older distro (according to GNU webpage, SUA support ended with GCC 3.3)

Answer (score 3):

Gentoo has a [Prefix](http://www.gentoo.org/proj/en/gentoo-alt/prefix/) target for Interix. You can try this but I'm not sure if it's up-to-date. It is basically a Gentoo installation (with package manager) inside your Interix system.

The Prefix solution should be easier to maintain that cross-compiling.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I'll be looking into Prefix.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "mingw" as an alternative compiler for windows to compile Linux applications.

Comment: Can MinGW target SUA? I've been searching on Google but the hits aren't very relevant.

Comment: No, I think it's not compatible.